# Deleting Multiple Photoshop CC Work Path Achor Points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path

When vectorising a jpeg image (OK, not a true vectoring, but creating vector paths for layer masks which create a crisp "vector like" images when resized) the process of selecting the outline using the Magic Wand or Quick Selection Tool and creating a work path creates a large number of anchor points which ultimately whilst working on the image, you don't need.

[image]

When using the Direct Selection tool, you can select a number of anchor points by dragging a selection box around them, and when you press the delete button, you can delete the anchor points, but it will split the workpath open.

How do you delete multiple achor points whilst keeping the workpath closed?

I have tried shift+delete and the same happens.

Comment: You should do that in the program you used to vectorize the image.

Comment: I am.  I am vectorising using Photoshop.  OK, not a true vectoring, but creating vector paths for layer masks which create a crisp "vector like" images when resized.

Comment: Can you possibly show what the problem is?  Why do the paths have a large number of anchors?  Did you create them that way?  If so, the problem could be solved by creating paths with fewer anchors in the first place.  Also, Photoshop has only very limited vector support.  It wouldn't be my choice for creating vector images.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Please see my question edit for example of excess anchor points after selecting the outline and then clicking "create work path"

Comment: That isn't a good way to create vectors - as I said, Photoshop is not really the right software. I suppose you could use the Pen Tool to create the vectors manually, or alternatively you could import the graphic into vector software like Illustrator or Inkscape, and auto trace the image, then you could simplify the vectors if there are still too many anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop is not a program optimized for advanced vector work despite having  vector tools. The specific vector manipulation options such as the one referred in the question, can only be found in vector drawing programs such as Illustrator or Inkscape.

I suppose you have done the vectorization from a selection using **Make Worth Path**, obviously those vectors are not useful. Delete them.

You must do it again by changing the **Tolerance**, the greater the number of tolerance, the fewer nodes but more imprecision.

- With a selection go to the **Path Panel Menu**> **Make Work Path**

[image: Make Path]

[image: Tolerance]

Comment: This answer is useful for future reference (I am already half-way through the complete image which has taken me hours) but what about my question?  Is there a way to delete multiple anchor points or am I just going to have to delete each anchor point individually one by one?

Comment: See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know why I didn't think of this before.**

Move some of the anchors to **roughly** where you want them, and leave the excess.

[image: rough vector anchoring with excess anchors]

When using the Direct Selection tool, you can select a number of anchor points by dragging a selection box around them.

[image: selection box around anchor points to be deleted]

When you realease the mouse, all the anchor points selected within the box turn blue.

When you press the delete button, the blue anchor points are removed, but the workpath will be open.

[image: Open workpath]

You can [use the pen tool to draw a line connecting the two open anchor points](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html#connect_two_open_paths) to close them back up.  This is **much quicker** than deleting each individual anchor point one by one.